# Why is QuestDB not showing me the data I just ingested?

Tags: database, time-series, real-time-data, questdb

I am streaming data into QuestDB using the ILP protocol with one of their official clients. I would expect to see the data available immediately after sending, but that's not the case.

If I go to the web interface, the table has been created, but if I run `SELECT count() FROM sensors` or `SELECT * FROM sensors` I am not getting any results.

The logs are not showing any errors either.

Thanks

**update**: If I check after a few minutes, the data is in there, but it always takes at least 5 minutes until I can see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be one of the most frequently asked questions by QuestDB's new users. Before QuestDB version 6.6.1 (released in November 2022), QuestDB would use a mechanism called ["CommitLag"](https://questdb.io/docs/guides/out-of-order-commit-lag/) to trade off ingestion performance and readiness of fresh data in your queries.

This was designed specifically for data arriving out of order (relative to the designated timestamp), but in many cases it would have side effects also when data was ingested in order. CommitLag defaulted to 5 minutes, but it could be changed (down to the millisecond) for individual tables.

The reason why this was needed for out-of-order data (or o3 in QuestDB terms), is because QuestDB stores data physically sorted by increasing designated timestamp, so data arriving late means the engine needs to rewrite the partitions where those data belong.

Starting from version 6.6.1, QuestDB changed the way it persist data to the table files, introducing ["Dynamic Commits"](https://questdb.io/blog/2022/11/25/questdb-6.6.1-dynamic-commits/). This new mechanism automatically decides how often to physically write to the table files. As long as data is arriving in order, writes are immediate and your data will be able in your `SELECT` statements straight away.

If data starts coming out of order (for example, due to network lag in the origin, or because the business logic allows for older data being sent), QuestDB will figure out how late the data is arriving and will adjust the write frequency in consequence. This heuristic is calculated once every second, so responding to changes in the ingestion pattern is very fast.

The new functionality is configuration-free and works out-of-the-box when you are using QuestDB 6.6.1 or above, so my advice would be to upgrade to the latest version.